# What is the correct way to check if bit field is turn on in php

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

What is the correct way to check if bit field is turn on - (in php) ?

I want to check a bit field that come from db(mysql) if is turn on or not.

is this is the correct way ?

```
if($bit & 1)
```

Are there other ways ?

I see somebody code that using  [ord()](http://jameslow.com/2008/08/12/mysql-bit-in-php/) function , it is correct ?

like `if(ord($bit) == 1)`

Comment: ord() returns ascii value of character string which sounds like a hackisk way of doing things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
if( $bit & (1 << $n) ) {
  // do something
}
```

Where `$n` is the *n*-th bit to get *minus one* (for instance, `$n=0` to get the least significant bit)

Answer (score 6):

I use

```
if ($flag & 0b010) {
  // here we know that the second bit (dec 2) is set in $flag
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit late but might be usefull for future visitors to this question. I've made myself a little function that returns all bits that are active in a certain flag.

```
/**
 * Shows all active bits
 *
 * @param int $flag
 * @return array
 */
function bits($flag)
{
    $setBits = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 32; $i++) {
        if ($flag & (1 << $i)) {
            $setBits[] = (1 << $i);
        }
    }

    // Sort array to order the bits
    sort($setBits);

    return $setBits;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(bits(63));
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `if($bit & 1)` is the correct way to check, according to [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

An alternative could be to do the check in your MySQL query.

Answer (score 2):

To get the correct bit, use this syntax:

```
$bit & (1 << $n)
```

Where `$n` is to get the (*n*+1)-th least significant bit. So `$n=0` will get you the first least significant bit.

Comment: in my case is ? $bit & (1 << 1) ? (in db set to 1 )

Comment: i see that in my case is $bit & (1 << 0)